# Count unique posts where user leave comments

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table for post's comments where user_id and post_id stored. So, every user can leave multiple comments for every post. Here is a simplified table create example:

```
CREATE TABLE `post_comments` (
  `post_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id_and_post_id` (`user_id`,`post_id`),
  KEY `post_id_and_user_id` (`post_id`,`user_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;
```

Ok, now I can get number of posts where specific user commented like this:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT post_id) FROM post_comments WHERE user_id='24394249647'
```

and it works fast with my 12M records. Now I want to get top 100 of commenters, so I want to count unique posts per user:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT post_id) as counter
FROM post_comments
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING counter > 0 ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 100
```

and this is 20 seconds query.... how I can improve it?

Comment: Consider storing ids as integers. It won't help much, but it may help a little

Comment: @Strawberry I have mixed user_id, it comes from external source like YouTube, instagram, Facebook auth.

Comment: @350D: "I have mixed user_id, it comes from external source(s)" -- then there's a potential for collisions. You should better have a *unique* internal ID and some mapping(s) to external IDs.